# Why the array is empty after observer?

Tags: android-room

I am trying to get the values from the Room database:

```
val cars = mutableListOf<String>()
carsDb.getAll.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { 
   cars = it.toMutableList()
   // cars.size = 5 
}

// cars.size = 0
```

Why can't I get the values outside the observer?

I am facing this issuing every time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem of synchronisation, the db call `carsDb.getAll.observe()` is likely asynchronous, so the `cars.size=5` you get inside the function is resolved later than the `cars.size=0`you got just after calling the db call (but before the request is resolved)

Comment: As you can see, the problem is that the array can't be used outside the observer function

Comment: Even if you wait for the db request resolution ?

Comment: the db is called `val carsDb: CarsModel by viewModels { CarsFactory((requireActivity().application as App).cars) }` I am new to `Room` and `viewModels`. Could you please explain why the values are only available within function, but not after that? Thanks

Comment: My guess is because the `carsDb.getAll.observe(viewLifecycleOwner)` is asynchronous so the main thread continues before request has been resolved. To verify that you could try to print in both places (inside and outside the observer call) and see what print is called first. If I'm right I think the print that is outside the function will be called first. Then you need a way to organise your code so the values resolved asynchronously are not needed by the synchronous thread. (For example if something needs the `cars` list once updated it should be called from inside the observer function.

Comment: So, I found this [example](https://github.com/velmurugan-murugesan/Android-Example/tree/master/RoomAndroidExample) which does not require the `observe` and works ok for me.